# Rounding Up a Number in Python

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to round up a number using math module in python.

So when I do,

```
print math.ceil(21/10)
```

I get '2.0' which is right.

```
print math.ceil(27/10)
```

I still get '2.0'

I want to get 3, since it is closest to 2.7

Could someone please advise a workaround.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you're looking for [round](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round)

Comment: @aruisdante Hi, Thanks for replying. But even     print round(27/10) is getting me 2.0 instead of 3.0. :-(

Comment: Ah right, missed the ``python 2.7`` tag. See @steveha's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want round:

```
from __future__ import division

print round(27/10)
3.0
print round(21/10)
2.0
```

`math.ceil` will always round up, `round` will round to the nearest

You only get 2 `from math.ceil(21/10)` because of how python2 handles integer division.

`21/10` in python2 is `2`

Answer (score 2):

You are being surprised by the division operator in Python 2.x.  With integers, it does integer division; `21/10` results in `2` and `27/10` results in `2`.

Use `21.0/10` and `27.0/10` and you will get the correct answers.

In Python 3.x, division of integers will automatically promote to `float` if the division isn't even (there would be a remainder).  You can get this behavior in Python 2.7 by using `from __future__ import division`.

By the way, pretty sure the integer ceiling of 21/10 should be 3.

Comment: Thanks a million. This works! But it's strange.
math.ceil(21/10)    gets -- 2.0  |  
math.ceil(21.0/10)  gets -- 3.0  |  
math.ceil(27/10)    gets -- 2.0  |  
math.ceil(27.0/10)  gets -- 3.0

Isn't there a foolproof way to get a perfect answer?
It would be great if you could please advise., Thanks again

Comment: ``pretty sure the integer ceiling of 21/10 should be 3`` yes, yes it should be, since the whole point of ``ceiling`` is to always round up. And @user3642558 that's for the same reason ``round`` wasn't working, it's performing ``ceil`` on ``2`` (integer division of 21 and 10) which is ``2``.

Comment: Thats the point,
ceiling of 21/10 is 2.0, while for 21.0/10 is 3.0
Thats strange

Comment: `21/10` does *integer* division with no remainder.  If you used `divmod(21, 10)` you get the answer `(2, 1)` but with `/` you just get `2`.  By having at least one number be a `float` you get floating-point division, which keeps a fractional part, and then `math.ceil()` has a fraction to round up.  When you get just `2` as the answer, and pass that to `math.ceil()` the `2` gets coerced to `float` but has no fraction.

Comment: right, wow, python is always surprising! Thanks to all who answered. I think @Padraic Cunningham finally has the right solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is Python thinks 27/10 are integers and so the evaluates that as 2. If you write 27/10.0 it will make them floats and the thing will work as you want.

Comment: math.ceil(21/10.0) is again 3.0
while we want it to be 2.0 :-(